# Get interface translation LID (Locale Id?) using source string value

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I'm using **User interface translation** in English to override system strings like Drupal 7's **String Overrides** module did. Works great. However, in my custom module, as I edit strings that run through the t() function, the **Source string** table in **User interface translation** is filling up with unused strings.

I'm writing a simple function to delete unwanted source strings one-by-one. The post at http://www.drupal8.ovh/en/tutoriels/89/delete-a-source-string-and-target-translations-drupal-8 provides code for deleting a translation once you know the LID (Locale Id?), which it suggests you get by inspecting the HTML of the displayed **User interface translation** page.

Question: Is there a way to look up the LID for a source string using the text of the source string?

I've read many posts, but don't see any that suggest how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK: Figured it out through trial and error. Here's the code:

```
$db = \Drupal::database();

$query = $db->select('locales_source', 'ls')->
    condition('source', $source_string)->
    fields('ls', ['lid'])->
    range(0, 1);

$lid = $query->execute()->fetchField();
```

UPDATE: Found a cleaner way. Here's the code:

```
$storage = \Drupal::service('locale.storage');
$string = $storage->findString(['source' => $source_string]);

if (!is_null($string)) {
  $lid = $string->lid;
}
```

I'm using this now in a custom module. Seems to be working well.